# Producing the same signature with WebAuthn

Tags: javascript, authentication, encryption, webauthn

I just started playing around with `WebAuthn` on localhost. I was given to understand that the signature value found in `credentials.response.signature` was signing `credentials.response.clientDataJSON`. However, for the same inputs / challenge for `navigator.credentials.get` I seem to be getting a different signature. My best guess is there is a timestamp or counter going somewhere into the value that is signed?

I can't seem to decode the `signature` or `authenticatorData`, which would really help me to visualize what's going on inside. I'm able to decode `clientDataJSON` as follows, anyone have sample code with which I code decode the other two aforementioned params?

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(credentials.response.clientDataJSON))
```

I also found when decoding `clientDataJSON` I get the occasional [extra field in Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/content/browser/webauth/client_data_json.md), which is a little annoying for my use case.

**My goal is to get the user to produce the same signature or hash each time when authenticating the same `PublicKeyCredential`**. Is there a way to do this? or are there other methods within the scrope of WebAuthn or outside of its scope to benefit from the biometric auth with which I can produce identical signatures or hashes from the same inputs?

Please forgive any misconceptions I might have about `WebAuthn`, I'm quite new to this amazing tech. I completely understand that this is not the original intended use of `WebAuthn` so a janky workaround may be needed.

Answer (score 3):

> **My goal is to get the user to produce the same signature or hash each time when authenticating the same `PublicKeyCredential`.**

This is actually a really **bad idea**. The whole purpose of signing a message with a random challenge is to avoid replay attacks. Otherwise, if an attacker somehow intercepts an authentication message, that message could simply be reused to impersonate the user.

> I was given to understand that the signature value found in `credentials.response.signature` was signing `credentials.response.clientDataJSON`

That is not accurate. The signature signs `authenticatorData + SHA256(clientDataJSON)`.

Both are variable. The `authenticatorData` contains a "counter" increasing each time the credential key was used to authenticate and `clientDataJSON` *should* (or *must* to be secure) contain a randomly server side generated challenge.

> I can't seem to decode the signature or authenticatorData, which would really help me to visualize what's going on inside. I'm able to decode clientDataJSON as follows, anyone have sample code with which I code decode the other two aforementioned params?

The signature cannot be "decoded", it can only be "verified" given the adequate public key. For the other paramters `authenticatorData` and `clientDataJSON` , check out the following link at the bottom, it will decode them.

https://webauthn.passwordless.id/demos/playground.html

> I also found when decoding clientDataJSON I get the occasional extra field in Chrome, which is a little annoying for my use case.

*I'm not sure*, I believe this is related to *localhost* testing.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer! I’m not intending to transmit this signature / hash as is. It will only be used locally and it’s a derived product of that, that will be transmitted and of course unique each time to avoid replay attacks. Sorry for the weird use case! Can the counter in authenticatorData be manually changed or is that all black boxed for security reasons?

Comment: The signature counter is implemented in the authenticator itself and can't be controlled. (Although authenticators that sync will generally fix the counter to zero to avoid needing the sync the counter too.)

Comment: @agl any further reading on this? sorry looks like I'm going down this rabbit hole to try to get my use case to work

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-sign-counter and generally search for "signature counter" in that spec.

Comment: @AntersBear Out of curiosity, what is the use case? Perhaps there are other ways to achieve it.

Comment: @dagnelies I would like to use WebAuthn or at least the biometric sensors on mobile to securely store and retrieve some information on the client side.

I'm looking at `navigator.credentials.store` right now but I think it's the same issue, I can't actually retrieve the underlying credentials only get the signature to show the user has it.

So I would need to add a server service to store it securely and send it back down etc, which really defeats the purpose 

Comment: @AntersBear did you manage to find a way to do it?
I am looking for the same solution :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a small, fixed bit of data associated with a credential then you may wish to investigate the [credBlob](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.1-ps-20210615/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.1-ps-errata-20220621.html#sctn-credBlob-extension) or [prf](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#prf-extension) extensions. Not all authenticators will support them, however. Many more will support `prf` but [support for that in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1106961) won't appear for a few more months. So there's not a great answer here yet, but it may work better than trying to fix the signature.

Comment: Hi that's interesting thank you! Anywhere where I can find the devices / browser that support these?

Comment: The latest Yubikeys will usually have the greatest support for CTAP protocol features. (I've a stock Yubikey Bio here and it supports credBlob.) In general, if you do a security key operation in Chrome on macOS or Linux, you can open chrome://device-log and see the supported feature list from the security key. For prf support, follow the linked Chromium bug and, at some point, support will appear in Chrome Canary behind chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features

Answer (score 0):

So, first things first, in general it depends on the signature scheme used whether the same signature will be produced when you use the same data as input. Check this question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26974/ where they discuss about it.

Now, coming back to WebAuthn (assuming that you use a signature algorithm that for the the same input will generate the same signature) let's look how the signature is generated. Here is a [small code](https://github.com/GramThanos/WebDevAuthn/blob/fb82126b2f02245f489362698d303d868f7129e0/js/webauthn-authenticator.js#L527) from my virtual authenticator that is responsible for generating the WebAuthn signature:

```
let authData = this._concatUint8Arrays(
    rp_id_hash,
    flags,
    sign_count, // The signature counter will always increase
    this._getAAGUID(),
    credential_id_length,
    credential_id,
    cose_key
);

// Attestation object
let attestation_object = {'fmt': 'none', 'attStmt': {}, 'authData': authData};

// ...

// Generate signature
let client_data_hash = new Uint8Array(await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', client_data));
let signatureData = this._concatUint8Arrays(authData, client_data_hash);
let signature = await Algorithms.Sign(this.private_key, signatureData);
```

You will notice that the data to be signed include the authenticator's signature counter which should increase each time you use the authenticator. This helps detecting replay attacks or cloned authenticator attacks (more info [here](https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1590)).

Thus, it is not feasible to generate the same signature.

If you want to look more into what is going on under the hood of WebAuthn you can have a look into my [WebDevAuthn project](https://gramthanos.github.io/WebDevAuthn/) and [browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webdevauthn/aofdjdfdpmfeohecddhgdjfnigggddpd) that allows you to inspect the WebAuthn requests and responses.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple hack, you can store data in webAuthN without using any server request, and restore it securely.

So you can create a secret, store it there, and retrieve it later.

I wrote a demo code for it in my question:
[How bad it is store data into webAuthN userHandle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78067132/how-bad-it-is-store-data-into-webauthn-userhandle)

not sure about the security implications of it or anything that I am missing in this solution though, and waiting for some smart people to give a definite answer about it.